# Change the context of a CXF JAX-RS REST API without changing the war name

Tags: rest, tomcat, jax-rs, cxf, war

I have a CXF JAX-RS REST API (say `My#WebApp.war`). So now I can access it like this.

`https://localhost:8080/My/WebApp`

Now I want to change the context (i.e. `/My/WebApp`) to `/Your/WebApp` without renaming the `My#WebApp.war` file.

Basically I want to access it like this.

`https://localhost:8080/Your/WebApp`.

I tried many different thinhgs, but no luck so far.